# Check if links are 404 and if so, then send sms

Tags: php, html, validation, cron, http-status-code-404

I am trying to figure out a php script to check a bunch of links from a separate text file and if anyone of them is showing 404 then the script should trigger a php file, which will send sms notification. I already have sms file ready and just need to trigger it.

For example, there are several links in links.txt (which is also uploaded on the server), such as

```
http://example.com/link1
http://example.com/link2
http://example.com/link3
```

These links are not necessarily offline, they may be redirecting to a non-existent page, while the main site is alive.

```
If example.com/link1 is down smsnotice1.php should be triggered
If example.com/link2 is down smsnotice2.php should be triggered
If example.com/link3 is down smsnotice3.php should be triggered
```

The reference to smsnotice1.php, smsnotice2.php, smsnotice3.php can be either in the main script or another php file.

If none of the links is down, then no notice should be sent.

I can run this script from a php server on a cron for frequent check.
Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Why not start at [HTTP GET](http://in1.php.net/manual/en/function.http-get.php) ? Please try it!

Comment: User `curl` to make requests, have only the headers returned and evaluate those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to request a copy of the page.
2. Check the HTTP status returned with `$http_status = curl_getinfo($http, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);`
3. If it's anything other than 200 send yourself an alert.

As for how to send an SMS, pretty much all mobile providers have an email domain that you can use to send an SMS to your phone, ie: 1235555555@mymobile.tld

Comment: Why suggest cURL extension over PHP HTTP functions?

Comment: @SparKot because PHP has no decent, built-in HTTP functions. Certainly none that give back the response code.

Comment: cURL is good - but `$response = http_get("http://www.example.com/", array("timeout"=>1), $info);
` will give a response that includes the response code. See link provided by SparKot in comment to original question.

Comment: @Floris `http_get()` is a function from a PECL extension.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I'm not a programmer, so I can't really put the above pieces together. I resorted to using uptimerobot.com in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open your text file with [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)
2. For each URL, do a [`get_headers()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php)
3. Check that `$headers[0]` contains `200 OK`

Comment: You can do this in one step without doing file_get_contents() first by passing the URL into get_headers(). Ex: if (get_headers($url)[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {// send text}

Comment: @Levi You need to parse the file `links.txt` containing the links first

Comment: Mathieu, my apologies, I completely missed that line when reading the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$url="http://site.com";
$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

/* Get the HTML or whatever is linked in $url. */
$response = curl_exec($handle);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
/* Check for 404 (file not found). */

if ($httpCode == '404')
        { echo 'yes';}
else    
        {echo 'no';}

?>
```